# Codeigniter uri->segment doesn't work in query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm passing some variables through the uri, I then collect them using $this->uri->segment(3) make an active record query using the value i collect.
when one of the variable is a composed word such as "first_last" the query returns null
even if i know the DB has such entry. If however it is a single word such as "first" the query works fine.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you enable your profiler and see what the query looks like? enable the profiler with `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE)` in your controller

Comment: I did, but the query seems to be very normal. what confuses me is that the query works sometimes. Maybe i need to sanitize my variable?

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see specifically how you're going about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the denied chars in the URL. See the config of CI and add "_" in the allowed char's regexp

Comment: that's not it. I have 
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
this must be class specific in my case and i'am starting to think it is user error...cause i have another controller that works perfectly well with the same calls. Will post the problem when i figure it out

Comment: It was a very silly issue with regards to the URL i was calling. moral of the story one has to get more sleep. sorry for wasting everyone's time

Answer (score 0):

change "first_last" to "first-last" also cause underscore are not good on urls, then see if it works ;)